# I reset fedora root password in recovery mode but fedora asks for password during login again, why?

Tags: fedora, password-recovery

I have a fedora core 4 whose password is unknown, I reset the password using the following commands :

in grub boot loader I put rw and init=/bin/bash and then I executed

> mount -o remount,rw /

then

> passwd

and finally

> mount -o remount,ro /

and rebooting 
ctrl+alt+delete

yet when I try to run fedora normally, after startup process I will get "incorrect password" message.

I want to know what is the cause of such message, or is there any possibility that the computer hdd is encrypted or something like that?

Comment: Update. Fedora Core 4 is **long** past sell-by date.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your commands in the GRUB environment would do. I can see you are mounting `/`, but the kernel is not loaded. What user are you running `passwd` as? Why would that affect the installed system? I am not saying it doesn't, I just don't know and it looks like it won't.

You *can* do this via GRUB but you will need to actually boot the system at some point. See [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-reset-any-linux-password/) for more information.

I recommend you boot into a live session. Then do (as root):

1. Mount Fedora's `root` partition (change `dev/sdaX` with the Fedora `/`):

   ```
   mkdir oldroot
   mount /dev/sdaX oldroot
   ```
2. `chroot` into this directory:

   ```
   chroot oldroot
   ```
3. Now run `passwd` and change the password.
4. Reboot.

Comment: thanks for your input, I investigate a little bit more on this peculiar case, and find out there is a custom drive installed(place unknown to me) by a programmer on this PC and whenever you type 3 wrong passwords in a row the values of /etc/passwd will be changed  now I am curious to know, is it possible to change the way of authenticating FC4? if so what files are going to be changed?

Comment: Don't really know, sorry. I suggest you ask a new question.